# Why the block element <h1> is appearing beneath another block element even though the display is default as block?

Tags: html, css

I am learning positioning and block model in CSS and I am confused why does the  element is adjusted from the top of the body even though there is a block element present.
why the div element is behaving like an inline-block?

Is this happening because I am using position = absolute?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}

.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.yo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
}

.big {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="yo">Yo</h1>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

[image: Hello being printed under the div]

Comment: Yes becuase you are using absolute, if you use position: relative then it won't happen

Comment: "Is this happening because I am using position = absolute?" Yes, becasue `postion:absolute` removes the element from the document's natural flow. That is its purpose.

Comment: ok I got it . "Absolute" disobey the display rule

Answer (score 0):

It is positioned fixed so it breaks out of the document flow